# Change hawtio port on Karaf

Tags: java, apache-karaf, hawtio

I have installed [hawtio](http://hawt.io/getstarted/index.html) in the couple of my Apache Karaf 2.2.7 instances by executing commands:

```
features:addurl mvn:io.hawt/hawtio-karaf/1.0/xml/features
features:install hawtio
```

The problem is that I have four linux boxes and four Karaf instances, so I have installed it on each of them. Everything is fine except that the hawtio console ports are different. I know that by default it should be started on `8181`. On two of my servers it started on: `8182` and on the other twos: `7181`. I am not sure, maybe `8181` is used by something, but still, how does hawtio chooses the port? Can I somehow get in control of this and change the port manually to always be the same?

Answer (score 2):

Hawtio is just a web-application running on top of Karaf and Pax-Web, therefore you should check the org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg on how the port is configured.